# CQ and Java EE application integration

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, aem

There is a JSP-servlets Java EE application (ecommerce web site) which is deployed on Tomcat. Now my requirement is to integrate this Java EE application with Day CQ to display content related static pages.

With a hybrid approach, where we maintain all the content related stuff in CQ and dynamic pages (ecommerce like checkout) in the Java EE container, I have the following challenges -

1. How could we use the Apache server to go back and forth between CQ and the Java EE container using redirection. Apache would be the front container for all the request and depending on the rewrite rules it would forward the request to either CQ  or the Java EE container ? Any example of this would be helpful.
2. Since CQ does not provide an OOTB session feature, how should I do the session management across CQ and the Java EE container? I mean when I go back and forth between CQ and the Java EE container.

Comment: I won't write an answer because I haven't tried by myself, but CQ can be deployed inside an application server. Doing this will make easy to handle transition between both contexts. Also CQ do handle sessions. You don't normally use them since there is a dispatcher between it and the user

Comment: Hi Gaurav, you've asked the same question four times, with deploy CQ into Tomcat mentioned twice. Is there a reason you don't want to do this approach? Also, I'd advise against fragmenting the discussion across multiple posts. If you want to add more details, you can always edit the question or title to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have implemented something similar for Virgin Media. There are basically three models available -- depending on which "actor" does request dispatching.

If CQ is to do request dispatching, you will have to write logic where CQ provides dynamic pages that proxy your eCommerce. Seems like not the way for you, since you already have a Java EE implementation of that.

If the Java app dispatches a request -- similarly you have to write some logic in the webapp that would "fetch", proxy and possibly enrich some pages from CQ.

Finally, you could ask a web server (in your case Apache HTTPd) to dispatch requests based on URL -- e.g. make all your eCommerce pages handled from a different domain (`sales.mycompany.com`), or be served from `/shop/.*` (use `mod_redirect`) and so on and so forth. In Apache you would then create two virtual hosts, one with a CQ Dispatcher, one just proxying your webapp. I think that may be the droid you're looking for.

Now, the only problem with the last approach is said session management -- as you're kind of maintaining two sessions. But do you really need a session with CQ itself -- not only with the eCommerce part? Well, if you do, then consider one of the first two approaches. And leave a suggested deploying of CQ within Tomcat as a last resort -- it usually gives me more problems than it solves.

Hope it helps. Remember to thumb up if it does :-)

Comment: We have not explored the option of deploying CQ into tomcat yet ? We don't know what challenges we may face while using that approach. But we had explored the other option of integrating the CQ with J2EE app. And we had also seen that session between CQ and J2EE app can be maintained using cookies or  Iframes . I am not comfortable using that same logic. 

That’s why I asking this question if there could be some other way of doing session management across these two when I go back and forth for ecommerce functionality in J2EE and static content in CQ.

Comment: Would i be able to maintain session between CQ and J2EE app if i deploy CQ as war in the tomcat server ?